# Show error message if username and password are wrong on the same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I know it's possible with jquery or ajax to show and error messsage in a div on the same page if the username and password do not match. can anyone help me to do it

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}
body {
    background-color: #194370;
}
.textfield {
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-size: 14px;
    word-spacing: normal;
}
.style1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="<%=MM_LoginAction%>">
  <table width="323" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="center">Enter Username and Password</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="84"><span class="style1">Username</span></td>
      <td width="218"><label for="username"></label>
      <input name="username" type="text" class="textfield" id="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="style1">Password</span></td>
      <td><label for="password"></label>
      <input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="  Log In  "></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASP

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<!--#include file="../Connections/VT.asp" -->
<%
' *** Validate request to log in to this site.
MM_LoginAction = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
If Request.QueryString <> "" Then MM_LoginAction = MM_LoginAction + "?" + Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString)
MM_valUsername = CStr(Request.Form("username"))
If MM_valUsername <> "" Then
  Dim MM_fldUserAuthorization
  Dim MM_redirectLoginSuccess
  Dim MM_redirectLoginFailed
  Dim MM_loginSQL
  Dim MM_rsUser
  Dim MM_rsUser_cmd

  MM_fldUserAuthorization = ""
  MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "source.asp"
  MM_redirectLoginFailed = "error.html"

  MM_loginSQL = "SELECT Username, Password"
  If MM_fldUserAuthorization <> "" Then MM_loginSQL = MM_loginSQL & "," & MM_fldUserAuthorization
  MM_loginSQL = MM_loginSQL & " FROM dbo.Test_Register_Users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?"
  Set MM_rsUser_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
  MM_rsUser_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_VT_STRING
  MM_rsUser_cmd.CommandText = MM_loginSQL
  MM_rsUser_cmd.Parameters.Append MM_rsUser_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 200, 1, 70, MM_valUsername) ' adVarChar
  MM_rsUser_cmd.Parameters.Append MM_rsUser_cmd.CreateParameter("param2", 200, 1, 50, Request.Form("password")) ' adVarChar
  MM_rsUser_cmd.Prepared = true
  Set MM_rsUser = MM_rsUser_cmd.Execute

  If Not MM_rsUser.EOF Or Not MM_rsUser.BOF Then 
    ' username and password match - this is a valid user
    Session("MM_Username") = MM_valUsername
    If (MM_fldUserAuthorization <> "") Then
      Session("MM_UserAuthorization") = CStr(MM_rsUser.Fields.Item(MM_fldUserAuthorization).Value)
    Else
      Session("MM_UserAuthorization") = ""
    End If
    if CStr(Request.QueryString("accessdenied")) <> "" And true Then
      MM_redirectLoginSuccess = Request.QueryString("accessdenied")
    End If
    MM_rsUser.Close
    Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginSuccess)
  End If
  MM_rsUser.Close
  Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginFailed)
End If
%>
```

i want it such that on click on the submit button, it validates and if it's right it redirect to the main page if wrong the error message should be shown up on the same page. what i currently have it redirect to a different page if the username and password do not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ASP, set your error redirect to go back to your login page but with a query string signifying that an error has occurred (modify the link to suit your project, I just made a guess):

```
MM_redirectLoginFailed = "login.asp?error=true"
```

In the HTML of your login page, add something like this where you want the error to appear:

```
<% If Request.QueryString("error") = "true" Then %>
Response.Write "<p class=""error"">An error occurred, please try again.</p>"
<% End If %>
```

Obviously you can customise your error mark-up to suit your design as you see fit. Anything between the `If` and `End If` will only be written out when the query string is set as in the login error redirect.

There are better ways to achieve this if you were starting from scratch, but at this stage it would mean large amounts of rewriting code; the solution I suggest is meant as a fairly quick and dirty way to achieve what you want.